# Manipulating data frame with R using dplyr and others

Tags: r, dplyr

I've created a sample data frame to help illustrate my problem. Imagine this setup but many rows and columns. It now looks like this:

```
> row1 <- rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=5)
> row2 <- sample(1:100, 15)
> df <- data.frame(row1,row2)
> t(df)

 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]  [,15]
row1 "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"   "C"   "C"   "C"      "C"   "C"  
row2 "33" "56" "44" "70" " 2" "15" "34" " 3" "24" "21"  "68"  "88"  "27"  "79"  "31"
```

I need to make it look like:

```
> t(df2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
row1 "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
row2 "33" "56" "44" "70" " 2"
row3 "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B" 
row4 "15" "34" " 3" "24" "21"
row5 "C"  "C"  "C"  "C"  "C" 
row6 "68" "88" "27" "79" "31"
```

Essentially, there are a set number of row headers with unique four code identifiers(the LETTERS in the example). I tried using different 'select' calls from dplyr and also the 'subset' call native to R.

Any assistance to point me in the right direction will be appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: My attempts started with seeing that  df[,1:5] isolates the "A's". I thought if I could subset every 5 columns, I could then rbind them all to one data frame. I created a vector with (1:5, 6:10,...). Then tried a for loop: for (i in vector) {df[,i]} to see if I could isolate all of them. It didn't work.

Comment: Is conversion to matrix intentional? I mean, why do you need to use `t`?

Comment: It is going to eventually be added to a larger data set with the LETTER, NUMBER layout as opposed to the other way. And yes, I had to coerce it back to a data frame do more manipulations. Problem solved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `split` to split your data by `row1` and then use `cbind` to bind it back together. Note that transposing converts all your values to `character`.

```
t(do.call(cbind, split(df, df$row1)))
##        1    2    3    4    5   
## A.row1 "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
## A.row2 "26" "59" "21" "85" "74"
## B.row1 "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B" 
## B.row2 "78" "60" "24" "53" " 3"
## C.row1 "C"  "C"  "C"  "C"  "C" 
## C.row2 "52" "34" "66" "98" "41"
```